# ldd not finding shared object (.so) for xerces

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, xerces, xalan, ldd

I am trying to run a sample executable provided with Xalan C++ library, which requires a the Xerces C library. But I am not able to properly link the Xerces shared object file.

```
mike@ubuntu:~/Xalan-C_1_9_0-redhat_80-gcc_32/bin$ ldd SimpleXPathAPI 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7765000)
    libxalan-c.so.19 => /home/mike/Xalan-C_1_9_0-redhat_80-gcc_32/lib/libxalan-c.so.19 (0xf7409000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf73ab000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf738e000)
    libxerces-c.so.26 => not found
    libxalanMsg.so.19 => /home/mike/Xalan-C_1_9_0-redhat_80-gcc_32/lib/libxalanMsg.so.19 (0xf7386000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf71d8000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7768000)
    libstdc++.so.5 => not found
    libxerces-c.so.26 => not found
```

I included the location containing the `libxerces-c.so` in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but `ldd` will not find it.

```
mike@ubuntu:~/Xalan-C_1_9_0-redhat_80-gcc_32/bin$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    /home/mike/Xalan-C_1_9_0-redhat_80-gcc_32/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

I even added a soft link to ensure the `.26` is included.

```
mike@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib$ ls -l
total 98308
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  25560971 Aug 28 13:39 libxerces-c-3.1.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  75080734 Aug 28 13:39 libxerces-c.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       962 Aug 28 13:39 libxerces-c.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        18 Aug 28 13:39 libxerces-c.so -> libxerces-c-3.1.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        14 Oct 21 10:31 libxerces-c.so.26 -> libxerces-c.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Aug 28 13:39 pkgconfig
drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff     4096 Feb 18  2015 python2.7
drwxrwsr-x 3 root staff     4096 Feb 18  2015 python3.4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      4096 Jul  6 15:42 site_ruby
```

The first time I had this `=> not found` issue with `libxalan-c.so.19` I solved it by adding the location of that file to my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So I can't figure out why the same fix is not working for the `libxerces-c.so.26`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It could be that your Xalan library was built in such a way that it's dependent library locations are hard coded into it.  I believe this may occur for common system libraries.  How and on what machine was your Xalan library built?

Comment: @AnonMail Unfortunately they are both precompiled binaries from the Xalan and Xerces websites. Does that mean that I am doomed?

Comment: I missed the part where you said you are having problems linking.  Can you show your link command and error?  It may be that your linker can't find the library.  In that case use the -L option to tell it where it is.  I believe LD_LIBRARY_PATH is only good for running the program - the GNU compiler does not use it to find library locations.

Comment: @AnonMail I think I mis-wrote when I said linking. I actually meant the issue is occurring when running the binary, not trying to link the library when compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does this produce:

```
cd /usr/local/lib
file -L ./libxerces-c.so.26
```

Chances are, this will print something like `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object ...`, in which case you are trying to point 32-bit executable at 64-bit libraries, and *that* doesn't work.

You need to download a 32-bit build of `libxerces`.

Comment: You're right, it says `./libxerces-c.so.26: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=802588c1d05e6bcb968d63fe050422d780f3612d, not stripped`